# $ (n-7)^2$ is $\Theta(n^2) $ Prove if it's true

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

$$ (n-7)^2 \, \text{is} \, \Theta(n^2) $$

Is this correct?

So far I have:

$ (n-7)^2 \, \text{is} \, O(n^2) \\ 
 n^2 -14n +49 \, \text{is} \, O(n^2) \\ 
 \begin{align} n^2 -14n +49 & \le \, C \cdot n^2 \, , \, n \ge 1 \\ 
 & \le 50n^2 \end{align} \\ $

$ (n-7)^2 \, \text{is} \, \Omega(n^2) \\ 
 n^2 -14n +49 \, \text{is} \, \Omega(n^2) \\
\begin{align} n^2 -14n +49 \, & \ge \, C \cdot (n^2) \; ,n \ge 1 \\
& \ge -14 n^2 \end{align}$

This proves it true right? Must both proofs have the same constant? I'm very new with Asymptotics.

Comment: It must be with a positive constant.

Comment: Can both constants in both proofs be different?
So would the second proof $ is \Omega $ be okay with a constant of $ \ge 1 \cdot n^2 $ alone?

Comment: Yes, the constants do not need to be the same, but they must both be positive.

Comment: The constants need to be positive, but the inequality only has to hold above some $N$, so you don't have to worry about irregular behavior in the low ranges. (for example, for $n>28$, you can assume that $n^2-14>\frac{1}{2}n^2$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier: $(n-7)^2 > (\frac{n}{2})^2=\Omega(n^2), \ (n-7)^2 < (2n)^2=O(n^2)$ for $n$ large enough, hence $(n-7)^2 = \Theta(n^2)$

Comment: Was the choice of a constant of $ \frac12 $ purely arbitrary for the $ \Omega $ proof?

Comment: Yes. You can get sharper bound of course.